# How to instantiate an array when a user inputs?

Tags: javascript

When a user inputs text I want to create an array with the name of the inputted text and add it to array logNum. I've tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
logNum.push(var document.getElementById("buttonInput").value.toString()[]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've yet created your logNum array, you can do this :

```
 logNum.push([document.getElementById("buttonInput").value]);
```

The `[something]` notation creates a new array whose first element is `something`.

Comment: Thanks! So the new array doesn't have a name.. just an index within logNum?

Comment: Yes. There is no point in giving a name to a variable if you want to get it from an array later.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understood you, but try this:

```
logNum.push( window[ document.getElementById("buttonInput").value ] = [] );
```

first, we generate out array: *window[ document.getElementById("buttonInput").value ] = []* this creates an array with a user-input name.

and remember that assignments always returns the value of right-hand-side. so new array will be returned.

then, push the returned value to logNum array.